# Green Plum cannot using all memory of server

Tags: greenplum

I am new to Green Plum. I have a single server installed GreenPlum(1 master instance, 6 segment instances), and we have huge data imported(about 10TB). as we all run it for about 1 month, the memory utilization is low(15GB of 128GB), but the cpu is almost 100% when we run some calculation on it.
It will report the OOM issue of segment some time. 
OS version: **CentOS 7.2**, Server Type: **VM**

Here are the os settings:

*kernel.shmmax = 107374182400*

*kernel.shmall = 26214400*

*kernel.shmmin = 4096*

for GP setting:

*gp_vmem_protect_limit=11900*

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If that are all of your os settings, then you are missing a lot. https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/6-7/install_guide/prep_os.html

Comment: That's not all settings. As we are new to GP, we involve a vendor to help install and config. But when we turn to them for this question, they always said that we should install  it on a physical machine, which disappointed us. That's why I turn to the community.

Comment: No, you don't have to always install it on a physical machine. Greenplum is available in GCP, Azure, and AWS and runs in vSphere.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. shmall should be <50% of RAM
2. you have one single VM (128GB) with gpdb master process and 6 primary segment processes.  Am I right? Do you have mirror segment processes? How many CPU cores does your VM have?
3. gp_vmem_protect_limit =12GB. This means you have 12GB x 7 (1master, 6primary segments) = 84GB.

1 single node VM to handle 10TB data? Your cpu is probably waiting for IO all the time. This is not right.

Comment: This is a testing environment, we have 16 cores of CPU. As a traditional RDBMS, it always occupy the memory, and keep hot data in it. Looks like GP always try to release memory, if like that, does that means data always read from hard drive?

Comment: you can think that there are 7 postgres servers running in this single node VM.   Each one reserves 12GB memory and reading 10TB/6 of data into memory to serve your query.

Comment: As the thing we can see is, the CPU is always go to 100% utilization, but memory keeps on 10%~11% utilization. 3 month before, the server memory utilization is 50%, but in one day the server have to reboot(patch). After that, the memory reduce to 10% till now. The query we invoke against 6 months historical data need 2 hours 3 month ago, but now it will take more than 8 hour on same data sets and cannot get the result. I want to know is there a way to check if some setting is wrong.